# Web API 2: Authentication and authorization with third-party access tokens generated in the browser

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, access-token, jwt

I am struggling with understanding how to implement the following in Web API 2's OWIN pipeline.

I am building an application that will allow users to log in with several third-party identity providers such as Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc. However, I want the authentication step to be performed **entirely client-side**. For example, Facebook provides developers a snippet of markup and JavaScript that perform the authentication within the browser, resulting in a Facebook access token--all without any calls to my API.

The Web API templates that ship with Visual Studio 2013 all seem to assume that the API itself is in charge of the authentication flow. I have successfully gotten this style of authentication working, but in my opinion it is not the responsibility of the API to perform this work.

Here is the approach I have been trying to implement (so far unsuccessfully):

1. Provide endpoints like `/authenticate/facebook` that accept the appropriate access token and return a JWT with "decoded" claims if the access token is valid. This JWT would have similar claims regardless of the third-party identity provider. For Facebook, I think this involves a call to Graph API's `/me` endpoint.
2. Store the JWT in the browser's localStorage for subsequent API calls
3. Send the JWT in the `Authorize` header for each API call
4. Avoid cookies if at all possible

My questions:

1. Is this an appropriate way to handle third-party authorization?
2. Should the JWT's expiration match the third-party access token's? I assume yes, but I want to be aware of any caveats here.
3. Where and how do I store the third-party access tokens for use on subsequent API calls? Do I include them with the JWT?
4. Is there a template I can use out-of-the-box, or perhaps an online resource that implements authentication and authorization in this way? I don't understand how to use Web API's many classes and features to implement this.

Comment: (Responding to an apparently deleted comment) Facebook's tokens are for Facebook's API, but--as happens so frequently with OAuth--they are also used to prove identity. That's why my attempted solution is to process the third-party access tokens using each provider's API and store application-friendly claims in a JWT for subsequent use. I had not considered, however, where to store the third-party access tokens. I imagine that's what the Web API template's use of cookie authentication is for, but I'm not sure. Web API will be involved somehow in the solution, obviously; I am just not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

I have this mostly figured out now. I believe my architecture choice is the correct one after much research, specifically into the so-called "assertion flow." I am using Thinktecture's Identity Server 3 project to act as my STS. I am using a custom implementation of `ICustomGrantValidator` to perform the validation of the Facebook access token and conversion to claims.